# What is GID in Internal Server Error?

Tags: linux, server, whm

I'm a totally noob when it comes to server stuff. I'm trying to log into WHM and I get this error:

"Internal Server Error

500

Could not fetch uid or gid for : root"

My question right now is, what is "gid"? I imaging "uid" is short for "User ID". I've searched far and wide on Google and I've come up with nothing for "gid" though. Which is embarrassing, I feel the response to the question I'm asking is going to be "Let me Google that for you"....

But anyways any help someone could give to clear up this term would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I get the Spanish version of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_identifier) as third result in Google Spain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Linux: Changing UIDs and GIDs for a user](https://muffinresearch.co.uk/linux-changing-uids-and-gids-for-user/) would note UID is "User Identifier" and GID is "Group Identifier"

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_identifier) has this bit:

> A group identifier, often abbreviated to GID, is a numeric value used
>   to represent a specific group. The range of values for a GID varies
>   amongst different systems; at the very least, a GID can be between 0
>   and 32,767, with one restriction: the login group for the superuser
>   must have GID 0. This numeric value is used to refer to groups in the
>   /etc/passwd and /etc/group files or their equivalents. Shadow password
>   files and Network Information Service also refer to numeric GIDs. The
>   group identifier is a necessary component of Unix file systems and
>   processes.

[UID Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_identifier) for reference.